# flex 4 air close second window

Tags: apache-flex, air

i have an air application that has a button when clicked opens a new spark.window component. in the window is a video player. the new secondWindow.open() method works fine. what i can't seem to do is close the second window when the parent window closes.

i have this:

```
//parent window
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                   xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                   xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                   minWidth="733" minHeight="653" creationComplete="main()" currentState="loginForm" applicationDeactivate="windowedapplication1_applicationDeactivateHandler(event)">

//close second window
        protected function windowedapplication1_applicationDeactivateHandler(event:Event):void{
        NativeApplication.nativeApplication.openedWindows[0].close();
        }
</s:WindowedApplication>

//second window
<s:Window name="secondWindow" xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                   xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                   xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="450" minHeight="323" windowComplete="init()">
//video player code is here
</s:Window>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main application:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
                       width="100%" height="100%"
                       creationComplete="_creationComplete()"
                       closing="_closingHandler(event)">

    <fx:Script><![CDATA[
        private var _testWindow:TestWindow;

        private function _creationComplete():void
        {
            butt.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, _butt_clickHandler);
        }

        private function _butt_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            if(_testWindow)
            {
                return;
            }
            _testWindow = new TestWindow();
            _testWindow.open();
        }

        private function _closingHandler(event:Event):void
        {
            var openedWindows:Array = nativeApplication.openedWindows;
            var i:uint;
            var count:uint = openedWindows.length;
            for(i; i < count; i++)
            {
                openedWindows[i].close();
            }
        }
        ]]></fx:Script>

    <s:Button id="butt" label="Open"/>
</s:WindowedApplication>
```

Child window (TestWindow.mxml):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:Window xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
          xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
          width="300" height="300">
    <s:Label text="Test Window" />
</s:Window>
```

Comment: kostik, my hat comes off to you. i ended up only needing the _closingHandler function to get the child windows to close when parent window is closed. i think i screwed up when i tried putting openWindows into the wrong type when I should have used an array. again thanks, john h